# Retaining subsecond time precision in date/time field in Geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, datetime

I have a set of points (essentially tracks) with subsecond time precision, that would be useful to visualise/analyse.  I have tried the "Convert Time Field" tool from string, float and double field types but the date/time field does not retain the sub second decimal. Also, the seconds value in the resulting date field is missing but replaced with the round millisecond value.

I have used String to Date with these formats: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s` ; `yyyyMMddHHmmss.s` to one, two and three decimal places.

Float/Double: `yyyyMMddHHmmss.s`

The results have been veried but most seem to lose the second values, either represent as `00` or the decimal value is represent in the seconds position.

There is not much on the forums or help pages or people having similar problems.  Any ideas?

As a side note, the "Convert Time Field" tool does not like decimal seconds as base 10 values. The tool fails to convert any values above ##.6 of a second.  So I have converted the decimal values to base 6. Therefore, 0.96 (base 10) converts to 0.58 (base6).

Comment: If you haven't already read it : https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/time/supported-field-formats.htm , it's not very clear but the tip at the bottom of the page seem to imply that you should be able to visualise your data at the millisecond level

Comment: Thanks for the reply J.R!  I had read through that help page yesterday before posting here.  It did give me some hope at the time but on closer inspection it does lead me to think there is some sort of problem/bug with the GDB date/time fields.

Comment: For example, "s = one digit of millisecond (0 through 9)" as stated in the page, does not appear to be now correct, as base 10 decimals do not compute.  Also the tips box states  '200911231030.560" as there example.  If you count the digits it is missing the whole second values.  It looks like an ESRI problem then!

Comment: I have contacted ESRI about the above issue and have accepted it is bug.  
BUG-000103915:The 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s' output parameter yields incorrect results when using the Convert Time Field geoprocessing tool.   Hopefully a fix will be not too far away!

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by the asker](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349436/is-it-possible-to-have-subsecond-time-precision-in-date-time-field-in-a-esri-g#comment579270_349436):

> I have contacted ESRI about the above issue and have accepted it is
>   bug. BUG-000103915:The 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s' output parameter yields
>   incorrect results when using the Convert Time Field geoprocessing
>   tool.

Comment: Esri code passes `struct tm` objects, which don't have milli-or microsecnds. There would need to be a new, enhanced time type to support sub-second resolution.